# Django DSL custom analyzer

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, dsl

i made my own custom analyzer,
I am using elasticsearch:7.5.2
when i run  python manage.py search_index --rebuild
the error is
raise RedeclaredFieldError(
django_elasticsearch_dsl.exceptions.RedeclaredFieldError: You cannot redeclare the field named 'name' on CarDocument

````
   class CarDocument(Document):
    name = fields.TextField(analyzer=ngram_analyzer)
    class Index:
        name = 'cars'
        settings = {
            'number_of_shards': 1,
            'number_of_replicas': 0,
        }

    class Django:
        model = Car
        
        fields = [
            'name'
        ]```
````